# Appropriate Numerical Method For Solving Natural Gas Pipe Sizes/Flows

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, finite-differences, finite-element-method

As an engineer, I periodically need to size a run of natural gas piping. There are equations provided by codes like National Fire Protection Association (NFPA) but this usually involves a manual iteration in a spreadsheet till pressure drop is "appropriate". I feel the need for a numerical method but I just can't get it going. I am ignorant in too many ways to capture it. Please help.

My first guess is use Newton-Raphson to solve continuity equations on these "pipes" but I don't want to distract if there are better solutions!

There are boundary conditions I can set on certain pipes. Pipe XX has to have a certain outlet pressure. One pipe's inlet will be another pipe's outlet.

I can also initialize every pipe with very close values; i.e. I know the flows for sure, I can guess the nearly appropriate size, I could even approximate the pressure drop across but I DO THINK THE PRESSURE IS ONE TO SOLVE.

I had better stop here and see what you all come up with. I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Nobody knows what actual mathematical problem you're talking about, so it doesn't seem likely anyone can help with it.

Comment: This could be an application of Green's theorem but you need to define your problem better. If you already have some equations, share them.

Comment: Every manual computation can also be implemented step-by-step in code in any other programming language. Then either iterate as you did or use a root-finder or solver procedure. For what you describe, many spreadsheet programs have a solver function available, you may have to reformulate the equation "input = output" to the difference "output - input = 0".

Comment: Could you provide one of these equations ? Many of them can be (at least approximately) inversed (I spend 35+ years as a mathematician in the gas industry)

Comment: "There are equations provided by codes like National Fire Protection Association (NFPA)" Perhaps, but I've never seen them. If you present the underlying mathematical model in a clear and self-contained way, I'm sure that there will be plenty of people (including myself) who will try to figure it out, but if not, I'm afraid you'll have to look somewhere else. @ClaudeLeibovici If you can help OP with translating his problem into mathematical language in case he/she has difficulties with it, that would be absolutely great :-)

Comment: @fedja. I totally agree but I do not access any of these codes. This is why I asked for one of the equations the OP uses.